# Error:Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0 on libgdx build.gradle

Tags: android, firebase, libgdx, firebaseui

i'm trying to add a login with Google on my game.
To do that i decide to use FirebaseUI (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). But i'm having problems to sync my Gradle file.
i'm reciving the error:
Error:Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0

here is my build.gradle (Project)

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        apply plugin: "eclipse"
        apply plugin: "idea"

        version = '1.0'
        ext {
            appName = "mystore"
            gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
            roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
            box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
            ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
            aiVersion = '1.8.0'
        }

        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        }
    }

    project(":android") {
        apply plugin: "android"

        configurations { natives }

        dependencies {
            compile project(":core")
            compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
            compile "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0" // Failed to resolve
        }
    }

    project(":core") {
        apply plugin: "java"


        dependencies {
            compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        }
    }

    tasks.eclipse.doLast {
        delete ".project"
    }
```

And here my build.grade (Module:android)

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 25
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.edney.mystore"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'br.com.mystore/br.com.mystore.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem in injection of `firebase-ui-auth` artifact to android module through root `build.gradle`.

Add `jcenter()` in repositories for all projects

```
repositories {
     mavenLocal()
     mavenCentral()
     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
     maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
     jcenter()
}
```

Sync & build.

Comment: i'll try this solution when go home.

thx @Abhishek Aryan for the help

Answer (score 0):

Add In your `app/build.gradle` file add a **dependency** on one of the libraries.

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI Database only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'

    // FirebaseUI Auth only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'

    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'

    // Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries above
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
}
```

You need to configure firebase on project level gradle.

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        // Add Classpath here..
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Also Add plugin in app module gradle at last line (bottom of gradle code).

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

*Don't forget to add `google-services.json` file in app folder.*
you can get this file from https://console.firebase.google.com

Comment: thx for the help, but i'm getting the same error:

    Error:(141, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0
    Error:(144, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0
    Error:(135, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0
    Error:(138, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0

Comment: thx again for the help. 
i tried classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' 
but the Failed to resolve error continue =/.

Comment: I created a new Android project without using libgdx using google-services: 3.1.0 and firebase-ui-auth: 1.2.0. Everything worked perfectly.
I suspect that I am putting
Compile "com.firebaseui: firebase-ui-auth: 1.2.0"
In the wrong place in the build.gradle of libgdx

Answer (score 0):

by **replacing** Implemenation with Compile in dependency solve my problem

before : implemantation'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'

after    : compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'